# Updating a pandas dataframe with a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Ye with Pandas Perspicacity,

I'm attempting to update a simple dataframe with another dataframe, and I'm running into trouble.  I have a master dataframe that I would like to update:

**Master_df:**

```
          color     tastey
name                      
Apples      Red     Always
Avocados  Black  Sometimes
Anise     Brown        NaN
```

I have some new data that I would like to update this dataframe with.  It might append new columns, add new rows, or update old values:

**New_df:**

```
          color   tastey   price
name                            
Bananas  Yellow      NaN  Medium
Apples      Red  Usually     Low
Berries     Red      NaN    High
```

I would like to merge these two dataframes such that an updated dataframe looks like:

**Desired_df:**

```
           color     tastey   price
name                               
Apples       Red     Always     Low
Avocados   Black  Sometimes     NaN
Anise      Brown        NaN     NaN
Bananas   Yellow        NaN  Medium
Berries      Red        NaN    High
```

I've played with [many](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) different commands, but I'm still struggling to:

- Not lose the index values I join on.
- Have common columns form one tastey column, rather than tastey_x and tastey_y.
- Have new data from new rows.
- Not have to hardcode the names of the new columns or new rows.

Finally, (while not shown in this example) I need to join on multiple columns.  i.e. I need to use 3 columns to form my unique key. (Though I'm sure a solution to the above example would expand to that case.)

I sincerely appreciate any help or pointers!  I hope the example above is clear.

Cheers,

A Pandas Pinhead.

**edit1:** I believe this question is different than previously asked questions because when I use `combine_first` I get this:

```
>>> Master_df.combine_first(New_df)

          color     tastey
name                      
Apples      Red     Always
Avocados  Black  Sometimes
Anise     Brown        NaN
```

**Edit2:** OK, I'm getting closer, but not there yet!  I don't want to generate `_x` and `_y` columns.  I want them to be one column, taking data from `New_df` when there's a conflict.

```
>>> updated = pd.merge(Master_df, New_df, how="outer", on=["name"])
       name color_x   tastey_x color_y tastey_y   price
0    Apples     Red     Always     Red  Usually     Low
1  Avocados   Black  Sometimes     NaN      NaN     NaN
2     Anise   Brown        NaN     NaN      NaN     NaN
3   Bananas     NaN        NaN  Yellow      NaN  Medium
4   Berries     NaN        NaN     Red      NaN    High
```

Edit3: [Here's an image of what I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5309.png) It's important that I don't have to hard code the column names ('A', 'B', etc.) other than the keys.

P.S.  Code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Master_data = {
    'name' : ['Apples', 'Avocados', 'Anise'],
    'color' : ['Red', 'Black', 'Brown'],
    'tastey' : ['Always', 'Sometimes', np.NaN]
}

Master_df = pd.DataFrame(Master_data, columns = ['name', 'color', 'tastey'])
Master_df = Master_df.set_index('name')

print(Master_df)

newData = {
    'name' : ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Berries'],
    'color' : ['Yellow', 'Red', 'Red'],
    'tastey' : [np.NaN, 'Usually', np.NaN],
    'price' : ['Medium', 'Low', 'High']
}

New_df = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns = ['name', 'color', 'tastey', 'price'])
New_df = New_df.set_index('name')

print(New_df)

Desired_data = {
    'name' : ['Apples', 'Avocados', 'Anise', 'Bananas', 'Berries'],
    'color' : ['Red', 'Black', 'Brown', 'Yellow', 'Red'],
    'tastey' : ['Always', 'Sometimes', np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'price' : ['Low', np.NaN, np.NaN, 'Medium', 'High']
}

Desired_df = pd.DataFrame(Desired_data, columns = ['name', 'color', 'tastey', 'price'])
Desired_df = Desired_df.set_index('name')

print(Desired_df)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) (an in-place operation) *before* [`pd.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
New_df.update(Master_df)

res = New_df.combine_first(Master_df)

#            color   price     tastey
# name                               
# Anise      Brown     NaN        NaN
# Apples       Red     Low     Always
# Avocados   Black     NaN  Sometimes
# Bananas   Yellow  Medium        NaN
# Berries      Red    High        NaN
```

Comment: Thank-you!  The issue here was the order of Master_df and New_df.  I've been scratching my head at this for days.